# LISP: Pass variable/symbol into function without evaluating

Tags: variables, lisp

I have a function and 2 variables that look something like:

```
 (setq A '(A B))

 (setq B '(A B))

 (defun myFunc (var1 var2)
   (if (equal var1 var2)
       'TRUE
       'FALSE))

  >>> (myFunc A B)
```

My issue is that I want Lisp to compare the variable NAMES, literally.  So in the function above, I would like it to evaluate to FALSE, because A != B, even though their "contents" are the same.  The problem is that when variables are passed, they seem to be evaluated immediately, so by the time we get to the conditional, their contents are checked for equivalency.

I read up a little on `apply` which seems to be helpful, but I can't seem to understand how it's used.  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node81.html

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: For what you want to do, you will probably need to use a macro. But, as others have mentioned, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible - lisp is [eager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation).

You have to either pass the variable names (quote them):

```
(myFunc 'A 'B)
==> NIL
```

or use a macro.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite strange wish to compare variable names for equality. =) I can't find where it can be useful, except, maybe in the code that is generated and evaluated in runtime. But then it's better to fix something in the code generator. Or I just can't understand the problem.

What should your function return when

```
(setf *somelist* '(1 2))
(setf var1 *somelist*)
(setf var2 *somelist*)
(myfunc var1 var2)
```

If this should evaluate to `t` and

```
(setf var1 '(1 2))
(setf var2 '(1 2))
(myfunc var1 var2)
```

this should evaluate to `nil` then you maybe want to use some other compare function, not `equal`. You can look at `eq` for example.

Or if you really need to do this, you can write a macro

```
(defmacro names-equal (name1 name2)
  (if (equal name1 name2) t nil))
```

But I still can't get the idea of this.

Comment: +1, but a comment on your advice to use `eq`: The example you provide *may* produce just one list if file-compiled, because file compilation may coalesce literals.